# How to remove "Powered by HumHub" from HumHub CMS footer?

Tags: php, yii, social-networking

I am using Humhub CMS for new social networking website. I already installed and everything is going smoothly.

However, during login / registration, there a "Powered by HumHub" link in footer. I was trying to remove that but couldn't find any way to rid it out. Humhub is developed by Yii framework.

Is there any way to remove that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can change that, but I am not familiar with humhub license model.

Check the terms at [humhub license](https://github.com/humhub/humhub/blob/master/protected/docs/license.md).

After that you can edit the footer at following locations:

- protected/modules_core/user/views/auth/_layout.php
- protected/modules_core/installer/views/_layout.php
- protected/modules_core/admin/views/about/index.php
- protected/vendors/yii/cli/views/webapp/protected/views/layouts/main.php
- protected/vendors/yii/gii/views/layouts/main.php
- protected/views/mail/template.php

You can check the [Github](https://github.com/humhub/humhub/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=powered) Page yourself.

If you already have installed, try a "search in files" with your favourite text editor.

Comment: Yes... licence is ok to make it change for personal use.

Thank you very much. Its really working. :)

Comment: Humhub is the best one so far I checked. But still there are some more problems. One of the problems is URL rewrite.... 

Is there any way to rewrite http://scholasticpoint.com/index.php?r=user/profile&uguid=7c1a76d1-ea4e-4b41-9dc7-b7c7f7c45665 URL to http://scholasticpoint.com/suchi

Comment: Yes, there is a way @tisuchi. It is pretty clear described in the docs under [Humhub GitHub Doc](https://github.com/humhub/humhub/blob/master/protected/docs/guide/administration/installation.md).

Comment: Because of Humhub appears to be Yii 1.1 (i am not totally sure about the correct version) you can check [Yii Tutorials](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) too.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update those that are using `v1.3.x` now using your `/protected/config/common.php` file you can enter the following to hide `Powered by HumHub`.

#### Without PrettyUrl Enabled

```php
<?php

return [
  'params' => [
    'hidePoweredBy' => true
    ]
];
```

#### With PrettyUrl Enabled

```php
<?php

return [
  'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    ],
  'params' => [
    'hidePoweredBy' => true
    ]
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

The `protected/humhub/widgets/PoweredBy.php` file is more of what you are looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Edit line 85 in:

protected/humhub/moudules/user/views/layouts/mail.php

Good luck.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `main.php` rather than `mail.php`?